# Why does the network sometimes split in the "Link-Walking Turtles" NetLogo example? How can I avoid it?

Tags: netlogo

I am analyzing NetLogo's [Link-Walking Turtles](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/Link-WalkingTurtlesExample) example to learn how to create simple networks where an agent performs a random walk in that network. The problem is that I need help understanding why the network breaks when applying the layout-spring function. I have tried different values of forces, but I need help to avoid this behavior while avoiding links overlapping.

Here is an image of what I mean about the network splitting

[image: Link-Walking Turtles network example 2]

For example, I'm avoiding the network split with:

```
to layout
  layout-spring nodes links 2 12 1
end
```

However, the links are overlapping:

[image: Link-Walking Turtles network example 2]

Here is the code of the Link-Walking Turtles example:

```
breed [nodes node]
breed [walkers walker]

walkers-own [location]  ;; holds a node

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape nodes "circle"
  ;; create a random network
  create-nodes 30 [ set color blue ]
  ask nodes [ create-link-with one-of other nodes ]
  ;; lay it out so links are not overlapping
  repeat 500 [ layout ]
  ;; leave space around the edges
  ask nodes [ setxy 0.95 * xcor 0.95 * ycor ]
  ;; put some "walker" turtles on the network
  create-walkers 5 [
    set color red
    set location one-of nodes
    move-to location
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to layout
  layout-spring nodes links 0.5 2 1
end

to go
  ask links [ set thickness 0 ]
  ask walkers [
    let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of location
    ;; change the thickness of the link I just crossed over
    ask [link-with new-location] of location [ set thickness 0.5 ]
    face new-location  ;; not strictly necessary, but improves the visuals a bit
    move-to new-location
    set location new-location
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that you actually have a single interconnected network from the start? If your setup creates more than one independent network, then this behavior makes sense

Comment: I am not sure. I assumed that: ask nodes [ create-link-with one-of other nodes ] creates only one interconnected network. If it creates more than one network, I fail to understand why and how to get the desired behavior. I included the complete code in my original post. I will continue to find out what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem. Each node just randomly connects to a single other node but there is nothing determining which node they connect to. Umit gave an answer that could work. It all depends on what kind of network you actually want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ask nodes [ create-link-with one-of other nodes ]` would have each turtle pick a random turtle that is not itself and create a link with it, which means that some turtles may choose the same turtle. That is why you may sometimes get a fully connected network and sometimes multiple unconnected clusters.

One way to overcome this is to check the entire network to ensure that you choose a random turtle from the fully-connected network. There is a Giant Component model in the library, which may give you an idea of how to check if a network is fully-connected.

Alternatively, here is a hacky way to achieve something similar: creating turtles one by one by choosing a random turtle to hatch the next turtle and forming a link with it.

```
  create-nodes 1 [
    set color blue 
  ]
  
  repeat 29 [
    ask one-of nodes [
      hatch 1 [
       create-link-with myself
      ] 
    ]
  ]
```

Note: we are creating one turtle first because otherwise, the first turtle created would throw a "found nobody" error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now it's clear to me. I had to stop working on the problem for a few days, but now that I'm back, this is the correct solution to my question.

I also started using the Nw extension, making creating different types of networks much easier. However, it is good to understand how to create fully connected networks without the extension, as it can be used for more customized or specific cases.